# Move marker with smooth transition with AGM-MAPS + Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using [agm-maps](https://angular-maps.com/) for the map in my ionic project. I have to move markers on map on specific time duration. I'm generating markers with `*ngFor`.

- Currently, markers flash when refreshing with `*ngFor` (even though position not updated).
- I want markers to move smoothly with transition when the position changes.